# How to configure RAID on Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3

Tags: motherboard, bios, raid

I am trying to set up RAID 0 in the BIOS of my motherboard: [Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3907#ov).

I have enabled RAID in the BIOS SATA mode, and I get the option to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to enter the RAID option ROM utility. When I enter the RAID option ROM utility, there does not seem to be any option to create a RAID volume. I have included some pictures.

[image: BIOS settings]

[image: RAID option ROM utility]

[image: Disks]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Press 2 for the "LD Define" menu and change the assignment there.